# parallax.js with ionic/cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, parallax.js

I am trying to use parallax.js with in an ionic view, when I use 'ionic serve' the plugin has the desired effect. But when I install it on a device (ios/android) it doesn't move based on the device motion. Has anyone been able to get this working in an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. it wasn't working because I was using the phonegap developer app to preview, once I installed it properly it worked as expected.